# symfony2 difference between error.message and error.messageKey

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am implementing a simple custom login form. I am following two different example , the official one http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html and this other one https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony2-ep2/logout#play which is substantially the same but with some differences.
Giving a look at the login.html.twig of the two examples, one of the differences is in the error message reporting where the first reports

```
<div class="error">{{ error.message|trans }}</div>
```

while the other reports

```
div class="error">{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
```

Please here's my  question : what's the difference between "error.message" and "error.messageKey" and what do error.messageData means in the second example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second example, according to the doc you provided:

"The error variable passed into the template is an instance of AuthenticationException. It may contain more information - or even sensitive information - about the authentication failure, so use it wisely!"

And the class associated:

http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Exception/AuthenticationException.html

So the variable `error` sent to the template is and object gotten by:

```
$error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
```

In the first example, the variable`error`is class constant gotten by :

```
$error = $session->get(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
```

And the class associated:

http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/SecurityContextInterface.html

So you can notice that both variable `error` share only the same name ! They are not instances of the same class

** **EDIT** **

This is an answer to your commentary, Both methods do the same job

### 1. First method

```
class AuthenticationUtils
{
    /**
     * @param bool $clearSession
     *
     * @return AuthenticationException|null
     */
    public function getLastAuthenticationError($clearSession = true)
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $session = $request->getSession();
        $authenticationException = null;

        if ($request->attributes->has(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
            $authenticationException = $request->attributes->get(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        } elseif ($session !== null &&   $session->has(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
            $authenticationException = $session->get(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);

            if ($clearSession) {
                $session->remove(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
            }
        }

        return $authenticationException;
    }



class AuthenticationException extends \RuntimeException implements \Serializable
  {


   /**
    * Message key to be used by the translation component.
    *
    * @return string
    */
   public function getMessageKey()
   {
       return 'An authentication exception occurred.';
   }

   /**
    * Message data to be used by the translation component.
    *
    * @return array
    */
   public function getMessageData()
   {
       return array();
   }
 }
```

So :

> $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

Followed by

> {{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}

Will return :

> 'An authentication exception occurred.'

### 2. Second method

```
interface SecurityContextInterface extends TokenStorageInterface, AuthorizationCheckerInterface
{
   const AUTHENTICATION_ERROR = Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR;
}

final class Security
{
    const AUTHENTICATION_ERROR = '_security.last_error';
}
```

So

> $error = $session->get(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);

Followed by

> {{ error.message|trans }}

Will return

> the last authentication error stored in session

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer, but there is one thing that is not clear. In a template I've wrote I have used the two different rows (the div with error.message and the div with error.messageKey) while in the controller I   was passing only the $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError() as $error. Strangely both have worked, and exactly <div class="error">{{ error.message|trans }}</div> has reported the same error message that reports when in the controller I pass tho the template $error as  $session->get(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)  . Are you so kind to explain me why ?

Comment: Thanks for the further explanation.

Answer (score 1):

in first case (`error.message|trans`) `error.message` just holds translation key.

second one (`error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security')`) little more complex:

- you have message key in `error.messageKey`
- you have data that will be used to fill placeholders in translated string (some kind of `sprintf('test: %s', messageData)` see http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#translations-in-templates
- you have message domain `security` (an optional way to organize messages into groups) see http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation/introduction.html#using-message-domains