# Twig message translation

Tags: php, symfony

I have been learning php and symfony for the last 2 days, working through a video tutorial as I need to learn to use php and symfony etc as the front end to a spring app written in java.

I am at the section on invalid logins and there is something I just cant get my head around, I dont know if its the syntax or what but it really isnt clear what is happening here:

```
{% if error %}
        <div>{{error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
    {% endif %}
```

I understand the error object is available implicitly as the framework puts it there but what is happening? It looks like the messageKey value is being piped into the trans function but what is that function doing?

If I just print out error.messageKey without the trans functions its the same, is the pipe symbol an OR and not a pipe in this instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pipe symbol is a twig 'filter'. It tell symfony and twig that the text at his left need to be translated.

Read more about it here http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html

From the comment :

> It looks like sometimes that exception Authentication could contain a placeholder array of values which are then used to transpose the error.messageKey which is the actual message string but in the example I am following the array of placeholders is actually empty and the string does not contain and %var% placeholders anyway so I always get the standard "Invalid credentials." `<div>{{ 'Invalid %vara% %name%' |trans({'%name%': 'Steve', '%vara%':'login'}, "app") }}</div>` – berimbolo

Comment: I read the docs but it doesn explain what is happening when the trans function is called and is passed trans(error.messageData, 'security'). If the error.MessageKey is being translated thats understandable, I have got that translating to a message using just {{error.messageKey|trans }}. What is happening when error.MessageData is passed in, and with the string security?

Comment: This thread talk about it and contain an accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30615754/symfony2-difference-between-error-message-and-error-messagekey

Comment: It contains an accepted answer about why it uses a different variable, error.message and error.messageKey, it doesnt really answer my question. What is the purpose of passing in error.messageData and 'security' to the translator function?

Comment: As an example these 2 both print out the same thing: <div> {{error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
      <div> {{error.messageKey}}</div>

Comment: If I am not mistaken, here '_security_' is a translation domain, that tell symfony to search the translation in the '_security_' file instead of the default '_message_' file (as explained in the doc). As for _error.messageData_ it could be a variable passed to the translation file but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help I knocked up the most basic example following the docs and I think I get it now. It looks like sometimes that exception Authentication could contain a placeholder array of values which are then used to transpose the error.messageKey which is the actual message string but in the example I am following the array of placeholders is actually empty and the string does not contain and %var% placeholders anyway so I always get the standard "Invalid credentials." <div>{{ 'Invalid %vara% %name%' |trans({'%name%': 'Steve', '%vara%':'login'}, "app") }}</div>

Comment: I accepted your answer as whilst it isnt completely clear in the docs what is happening I was able to write the example which was self explanatory to me...